# Determine NFS usage based on client

Tags: linux, centos, nfs

We have big NFS server (~50TB of data, millions of files). 12x 6TB SATA disks w/ SSD cache (MegaRAID CacheCade). CentOS 7. 1x Xeon E5-2620

Our problem is that we have ~100 processes from 6 servers connected to this NFS server causing a lot of load. Mixed read / write actions.

We're trying to find a way to understand what causes the load - which client (IP), which export and hopefully which directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireshark (and it's tool set) is your friend.

run on a command line:

`$ tshark -n -f 'port 2049' -q -Y rpc.replystat -Tfields -E header=y -e frame.time -e frame.number -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e nfs.main_opcode -e rpc.time`

this will give you nfs packes. Capture for some time and redirect the output into a file:

```
$ tshark .... > dump
^C

$ awk '{ print $8 }' dump | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -k 1 -r
```

This will give you the top clients.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, 
Your suggestion will allow me to get the client IP, but no more details.
Any other suggestions? Something that'll allow me to get more details?

Comment: By knowing the client, you can find export directory as well. With wireshark you can see the operations client sends and with directory it is ( usually identified by file handle).

Comment: packetbeat from elastic.co now has a NFS traffic support: https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/packetbeat.